# How to make and run a service periodically?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app (java) that has a background service.

The function of the service is to send to a webService the battery level of the android device.

Everything is already working as follows:

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initService();
}

public void initService() {
        intentService = new Intent(getBaseContext(), service.verifybattery.class);
        try {
            startService(intentService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String teste = e.toString();
        }


   }
```

ClassService

```
public class verifybattery extends Service{


    private boolean ativo;
    private int cont;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        cont = 0;


    }

    public String getIP(){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        String strIP = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
                (ip & 0xff),
                (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
                (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
                (ip >> 24 & 0xff));
        return strIP;
    }


    private void processa() {

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

        Double batteryPct = level / (double)scale;

        SimpleDateFormat formataDataHora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - dd/MM");
        Date dataHora = new Date();
        String dataFormatada = formataDataHora.format(dataHora);
        String nome;
        //String modelo = Build.MODEL.substring(0,19);
        String modelo = Build.MODEL;

        String serial = Build.SERIAL;
        String ip = getIP();

        if(PrincipalActivity.mesa != null){
            nome = PrincipalActivity.mesa.getNomeAmigavel();
        }
        else{
            nome = "?";
        }

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("id", 0);
            obj.put("nome", nome);
            obj.put("modelo", modelo);
            obj.put("serialNumber",serial);
            obj.put("ip", ip);
            obj.put("bateria",batteryPct);
            obj.put("atual", dataFormatada);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String response = "";
        try {
            response = new PutJson("Enviar nivel da Bateria", this,obj).execute(cardapioDigital.enviarBateria(PrincipalActivity.ServerCardapio, serial)).get();
            if(!response.equals("")){
                PrincipalActivity.ServerCardapio.setConectado(true);
            }
            else{
                PrincipalActivity.ServerCardapio.setConectado(false);
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(batteryPct), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        processa();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

The problem is that mainActivity's onCreate only runs once in the app's lifecycle. I'd like to run the service every 5 min (example).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerifyBattery.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 300*1000, pintent);
```

This way your service should be fired even if the app is in background.

P.S.: You should use camel case to name your classes if you want to follow the standard styles ( verifybattery -> VerifyBattery )

Comment: I'm new to android, sorry. Where did I put this code?

Comment: Where you want to start the service. It could replace the code in `initService()` in MainActivity in your case.

Comment: How are you ... after x minutes ... will the service run again? 1, 2, 3 services in memory or at each execution the process is killed?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one option Foreground service